# User issue with Flutter Revenuecat providing free trial with promo code

Tags: flutter, google-play, revenuecat

I am using revenucat to manage subscriptions in my app. But I noticed a problem. I have promo codes that I created on google play for my user. With this code, the user can use 3 months free of charge. When the user logs in on another device, I can't get the information that the user is in the trial period. Therefore, the purchase screen appears again. how can i solve this. I understand from the code below that the user is a premium member.

```
  Future updatePurchaseStatus() async {

final purchaserInfo = await Purchases.getCustomerInfo();

final entitlements = purchaserInfo.entitlements.active.values.toList();

_entitlement =
    entitlements.isEmpty ? Entitlement.free : Entitlement.premium;

if (entitlements.isNotEmpty) {
  _entitlementInfo = purchaserInfo.entitlements.active.values.last;
}
notifyListeners();
}
```

Comment: Have you solved the issue? same here. Having a short deadline, I appreciate any suggestion in this regard.